# Dlib library can't find any STL template in iOS project (Xcode 8)

Tags: ios, xcode, c++11, stl, dlib

I'm trying to add **Dlib** library to my **iOS** project in **Xcode 8.3.3**.
I've tried to use [this cocoapod](https://cocoapods.org/pods/dlib) and also tried to compile it myself but every time I get this:  `.../Pods/Headers/Public/dlib/dlib/image_processing/scan_image.h:6:10: 'vector' file not found`
or even
 `.../Pods/dlib/build/install/include/dlib/algs.h:17:10: "Dlib requires C++11 support.  Give your compiler the -std=c++11 option to enable it."
.../Pods/dlib/build/install/include/dlib/algs.h:93:10: 'string' file not found`
I've properly configured Xcode project and added every necessary dlib linker flags.
[Project Build settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pyz7b.png)
Everything I'm trying to implement in Objective-C++ is contained in one `.mm` file.

I've tried everything. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put everything in one `.mm` file. `Bridging-Header` should import only `.h` or `.m` files.

Comment: Have you got any solution, I am facing same issue while integrating dlib with xcode 9.